# What are the theoretical bounds on the Gas Giants' Cores

Tags: planets, solar-system

According to the popular Solar System formation models, what are the bounds on the Gas Giants' cores (note I am only interested in the bounds for our Solar System).

For example according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Internal_structure) on Jupiter

> Assuming [a core] did exist, it may have shrunk as convection currents of
>   hot liquid metallic hydrogen mixed with the molten core and carried
>   its contents to higher levels in the planetary interior.

This suggests that a core would shrink over time, which would put an upper bound on the size today.

Are there other bounds?  I would like numbers together with some reasons for those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

My advise on this question is to follow the data from the Juno spacecraft, which is now successfully in Jovian orbit. I suspect that a lot of phenomenology about Jupiter and related gas giants might be run through a paper shredder, and maybe a few will be supported. This spacecraft is tasked to address just this and related questions.

I am no expert on this, but as I understand the argument for a solid core in Jupiter and other gas giants it is that given their mass without a solid core they would have smaller volumes.

Lots of planetary models in the past have been thrown out as spacecraft actually reach planets and perform measurements. I suspect the same will happen here. We are fortunate enough to live in an age where we can get the real data on these things.